# Restore decals of vintage Kestrel 4000

Tags: road-bike, restoration

Does anyone know a company that specializes in reproducing vintage bike stickers.  I have a Kestrel 4000 that I would like to restore.  The bike manufacturer has none. I have heard back from one 3rd party company and they could not help me.
(Victory Circle Graphix)

Comment: A quick google of "vintage bike decal" returns sites like http://www.velocals.com/ and https://h-lloyd-cycles.myshopify.com and http://cyclomondo.net/

Comment: Googling ""kestral 4000 decal" returns links like https://www.ebay.com/itm/KESTREL-4000-Stickers-Decals-Bicycles-Bikes-Cycles-BMX-DIFFERENT-COLORS-55D-/231838258273 and https://designstickers.blogspot.co.nz/2011/11/adesivo-bike-kestrel-4000-pro-sl.html and http://www.yellowjersey.org/ksdecal.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because lack of research.  If it can be solved with one quick google, its not really a long-term useful question for SE.  Sorry - It does look like a stunning bike though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can create the graphics there are many online services that will create custom stickers or decals for you.

Presumably creating the decal images in the first place is the difficult part. Perhaps you can search for images of the original decals online.